# SharePoint List Not Working As Webpart

Tags: list, web-part, list-view, large-lists

I am trying to upload a webpart view of a list with over 1,000 items in it. When I upload the webpart from my site collection gallery, it appears as the whole list. When I go into webpart properties to change the view to only show 150-300 items grouped together, it crashes instantly before I can manipulate any property.

I am assuming that the list is too large, however this list is critical to my organization, and I do not know how to manipulate it prior to uploading it as a webpart. Any ideas?

Comment: why are you trying to upload a webpart list view? is this a datasheet view or custom webpart ?

Comment: It is a little hard to explain, but as if adding any regular list like contacts, to your homepage, I’m adding a list with a data source from another site within the collection. The data’s our evening is in tact and it works fine with smaller lists, but this particular list breaks.